# Schengen Visa for Family members of EU/EEA nationals

Tags: visas, schengen, eu-citizens

I’ve heard about the accelerated visa procedure for family members of EU/EEA nationals. I’m a Filipino citizen, who lives and studies in the Philippines, but my father is a naturalized British citizen. I’m not sure if this procedure will apply to me and I don’t know how the procedure works.

I had a look at the form, and there are questions that I don’t have to answer if I qualify under this procedure, however I don’t want to assume that I qualify and not fill my forms correctly. I guess it’s the assurance that I’m asking here.

But if the procedure applies to me, can I provide my university letter as proof to convince the consulate that I will return home?

Comment: According to this https://eumovement.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/requirements-for-a-short-stay-visa-family-of-eu-citizen/ if you qualify, you do not need to provide proof of intention to leave

Comment: @Traveller, thank you for this, this is really helpful. This also means that I don’t need to provide a prebooked return ticket, is that correct?

Comment: @itsmr correct.  A prebooked return ticket is in any event not an absolute requirement for a Schengen visa.  The first question, though, is *are you planning to travel with your father?*

Answer (score 2):

As noted in a comment, you don't have to provide any evidence of your intention to leave if you apply for a visa under EU freedom of movement.  However, to qualify, you must

- be *traveling with* your father, or *traveling to join* your father.
- under 21, or dependent on your father or his spouse.

Your application should therefore include

- proof that your father is a citizen of the UK (normally a copy of his passport)
- proof of your relationship (normally your birth certificate, naming him as your father)
- if you are 21 or older, evidence of your dependence on your father or his spouse.  This could include

  - Bank statements (his and yours) showing transfers of money
  - Receipts for payment of university tuition
  - Evidence that he pays for your accommodation and upkeep directly
- evidence of your planned travel together to the Schengen area, or of his presence there before you arrive.  For a pleasure trip, evidence of accommodation and transportation would probably suffice.

If you are planning to visit the Schengen area without your father, then you should submit a regular Schengen visa application.

Comment: Yes I’m planning to travel with my father and I’m 19 years old. Would an itinerary do, or do we have to provide flight and hotel bookings? We have hotel reservation but what I don’t want to do is book a flight until I have a visa. And will an invitation letter confirming that we’re traveling together helps?

Comment: @itsmr you should never book a flight before getting a visa.  An itinerary should be sufficient in this case.